# Convert a String to an Array in Javascript without using split() or any built-in methods and with no more than 1 parameter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

Convert a String to an Array in Javascript without using split() or any built-in methods?

input:

```
str = "Iam a fullstack javascript developer"
```

output:

```
arr = [ 'Iam', 'a', 'fullstack', 'javascript', 'developer' ]
```

confirmation:

```
console.log(arr[0]) // Iam
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
function stringToArray(str) {
    let arr = [''];
    let j = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == " ") {
            j++;
            arr.push('');
        } else {
            arr[j] += str.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

const arr = stringToArray("Iam a fullstack javascript developer")
console.log(arr[0]) // Iam
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str="Iam a fullstack javascript developer";
var strCharArr;
[...strCharArr]=str;
var arr=strCharArr.reduce((acc, cv)=>{if(cv==" ") acc.push(""); else acc[acc.length-1]+=cv; return acc;},[""]);
console.log(arr);
```

`[...strCharArr]=str` splits the string into an array of characters.
`reduce` starts with an array of one element of empty string (`[""]`),
and either adds characters, or, in case of a space, adds an empty string element.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive approach with using `indexOf` and `slice`

```js
str = "Iam a fullstack javascript developer";

const split = (str, arr) => {
  const index = str.indexOf(" ");
  if (index > -1) {
    arr.push(str.slice(0, index));
    split(str.slice(index + 1), arr);
  } else {
    arr.push(str);
  }
  return "";
};

const chunks = (str) => {
  const arr = [];
  split(str, arr);
  return arr;
};

console.log(chunks(str));
```